# FIREBASE WARNING: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

According to the documentation, most of the firebase-database verbs return promises. Yet I cannot call `.then()` on `.once()` or `.remove()` or `.set()`

This is the version I am using:

4.12.0

Here is the error

```
 FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Here is the specific example:

```
   collab_ref = new Firebase(FBURL + 'collaboration_songs').child(collaboration_id);
   return collab_ref.remove().then(function(){
          return cb();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs the right way for initialize a firebase app, from 3.x and higher, is this way.

**Init**

```
var config = {
  apiKey: "apiKey",
  authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

**And have fun**

```
var niceNode = firebase.database().ref().child('collaboration_songs')
.remove()
.then(resolve => { return ':)'}, (reject) => return ':(');
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start